# Взвешенное среднее двух списков, используя LINQ-выражение

Tags: c#, linq

У меня есть два списка, например:

```
List1 = new List<int>{4, 6, 9},  
List2 = new List<int>{12,3, 7}
```

Как найти взвешенное среднее этих списков, используя лямбда-выражение? (без циклов).

Результат должен получится такой:

```
weightedAverage = (4*12+6*3+9*7)/(12+3+7).
```

Answer (score 7):

Давайте решать задачу по частям.

Чтобы найти сумму элементов списка, проще всего воспользоваться LINQ-функцией `Sum`. Знаменатель у нас получается `List2.Sum()`.

Теперь, в числителе нам нужно подсчитать попарные произведения (а суммировать мы умеем уже). Для того, чтобы подсчитать попарные чтобы-то-ни-было, используется `Zip`, в который вторым аргументом передаётся лямбда-функция, которая будет применена к парам элементов. Числитель получается `List1.Zip(List2, (x, y) => x * y)`. Не забываем добавить в конец `.Sum()`, чтобы получить сумму этих самых попарных произведений.

Выходит:

```
var weightedAverage = List1.Zip(List2, (x, y) => x * y).Sum() / List2.Sum();
```

Ещё один момент: когда вы считаете средневзвешенное 1 и 2 с весами 1, вы ведь хотите получить 1.5, верно? Значит, при делении неплохо бы преобразовать к `double`, иначе получим целочисленное деление.

Итого, окончательный ответ

```
var weightedAverage = (double)List1.Zip(List2, (x, y) => x * y).Sum() / List2.Sum();
```

Comment: Не лучше ли приводить к double перед умножением, чтобы избежать переполнения?

Comment: @Qwertiy: С другой стороны, умножение в `double` потенциально неточное, лучше тогда уж скастить в `BigInteger`

Comment: Точное, если за 2^53 не вылазить. А у инта только 2^31.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, `2^31 * 2^31` уже `2^62` по идее.

Comment: Ну это да) Но обычно столько не надо)